# How to check if input is an integer and repeat until a valid input is recieved

Tags: java, validation

I have a simple program that calculates a pay rate. I am aware that a simple  while statement should be used, but unsure of how I could best implement it. Basically so I can repeatedly ask for the pay rate until an integer is received.

E.g if the user inputs "cat", the system should display a warning message and continue to print that message until an integer is received.

What I have:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your hourly pay rate");
    if(user_input.hasNextInt()){
        payment = user_input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your hourly pay rate is " + payment + " dollars p/h");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
    }
```

Comment: Why is `while (!user_input.hasNextInt())` not acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the do-while loop with infinite loop. Once you find the int value, break the loop. Use the try-catch to handle the exception throws for other inputs.

```
    do {
      System.out.println("Please enter your hourly pay rate");
      String str = user_input.nextLine();
      try {
        payment = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
        if (payment <= 0) {
          System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
          continue;
        }
        System.out.println("Your hourly pay rate is " + payment + " dollars p/h");
        break;
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
      }
    } while (true);
```

**Output:**

```
Please enter your hourly pay rate
string
Please enter a valid input
Please enter your hourly pay rate
123
Your hourly pay rate is 123 dollars p/h
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/wOB1Y1)

Comment: I don't thinks so. Can you provide, how did you run it.

Comment: Worked for me, was wondering if this would work for a negative integer or 0?

Comment: @shellpottassium It will work for any int, please try it out.

Comment: Sorry, bad wording. Would I be able to also check for negative integers/ 0's as an input (obviously because they are not valid either).

Comment: It works, i tried with `nextInt()` not with `nextLine()` :(

Comment: Any idea how i could alter this again so that it checks for if the user inputs e.g 0 or -12

Comment: @shellpottassium I tried but could not make it. Why you are not using the nextLine().

Comment: @YoungHobbit No problem, maybe ill post another Q.

Answer (score 0):

As @Luke Park mentioned you simply could

```
while(!user_input.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
}
payment = user_input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Your hourly pay rate is " + payment + " dollars p/h");
```

Comment: Did you test this? For any one wrong input it will go to infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
    boolean gotIn = false;
    while (!gotIn) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter number ");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
            scan.close();
            gotIn = true;
        } catch (RuntimeException nfe) {
            System.err.println("Invalid input, Enter only numbers ");
        }
    }
```

but creating a new Scanner every time, @YoungHobbit solution is correct.